# How to make the video display from sdcard in android?

Tags: android

Hi I need to display the videos from sd card. I kept my video in sd card and tried with following code. But the video is not displaying....Please help me where I went wrong....

My Code:

```
package com.videoapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class NewvideoappActivity extends Activity
{
    private VideoView vView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        vView.requestFocus();
        vView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/watch.3gp");
      vView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vView.start();
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<VideoView
   android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/myvideo.3gp"));
vv.start();
```

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video
see this example

Comment: hi I have to display only from sd card

Comment: Hi thank you for the link..I executed the example from that link and tested in my tablet. But it is displaying the error message as "there is problem parsing the package"

Comment: I am new to android,I used this code I can see Video static (not running,only image from video) and controller pls tell me where I m wrong.

Comment: Hi I developed the app in 2.3.3 version and installed in samsung tablet(3.2)...when i installed it is displaying nothing except a blank screen..Please help me....I need it urgently